# Automate Text Replacement Logic in a Microsoft Word 2007 Document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have a letter written in MS Word 2007 that I wish to modify and send to several different people. I need to personalise each letter by changing a few words, sentences and paragraphs, as well as cater for a bit of logic (i.e. sentence building logic and "if this word exists, then print that" sort of thing), so I want to create an application (Word Add-In, VBA macro, Template, something else I assume?) that prompts the user for such words, sentences, paragraphs and other options for replacement in the document.   What is the quickest and easiest way to do this, apart from using "Find and Replace" (which I would have to do dozens of times for each letter, and which I believe doesn't cater for the more complicated logic)?

Comment: All these options are available with mailmerge without writing any code.

Comment: Thanks Remou, that's exactly what I wanted.  If you leave an answer below I'll credit you.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these options are available with mailmerge without writing any code. Now credit me! :)